# Issue with remembering the playback position in PotPlayer

Tags: video-playback

I use PotPlayer as my default video player, and I like its functionality very much, especially that it remembers the positions where I left off watching the last time, in each playlist I have created. But, while it works perfectly when I turn on PotPlayer or when I switch between the playlists within it, it is not so when I double click to open an individual video file. When I double click the file it opens in "Default Playlist" and when I want to get back where I left off on the previous list it starts with the first video in the playlist instead with the last watched video. I've tried changing all kind of settings in PotPlayer, but nothing worked. Any way this problem can be resolved?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

**To enable this option on Daum PotPlayer:** 
Access PotPlayer's main menu by right-clicking on PotPlayer > Playback >  Check "Remember played position.
I seriously suggest you to do it, it has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remember last played position within a playlist:

To enable this option on Daum PotPlayer, access the Preferences window by tapping F5 > Playback > Playlist. Check "Remember played position within a playlist".

Answer (score 1):

In Addition with Eddy B.

"To enable this option on Daum PotPlayer: Access PotPlayer's main menu by right-clicking on
**PotPlayer > Playback > Check** "Remember played position. I seriously suggest you to do it, it has worked for me."

**If this still does not work** this means you have your default window size sat to 1x video output size.

Change it to
***potplayer>Playback>Default window size*** to ***"do not use"*** option.
Make sure you checked these three options.
[Picture of potplayer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tnpi.png)